# Databricks-connect Java connects to local instead of remote

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I have a Java application that connects to an Apache Spark cluster and performs some operations. I'm trying to connect to a Databricks cluster on Azure, using databricks-connect 7.3. If I run from the terminal `databricks-connect test`, everything works perfectly. I'm following their [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html), I included the jars in IntelliJ, added `spark.databricks.service.server.enabled true` to the cluster in Databricks and used the following to create the SparkSession:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .master("local")
                .getOrCreate();
```

The problem is that this command connects to a local cluster that is instantiated at runtime, and does not connect to the remote Databricks cluster. Am I missing something?

Comment: I found the problem, the previous dependencies (from maven) to spark-core and spark-sql where still in the class path. Removing them and exclusively using those of databricks-connect solved the issue.

Comment: also remove `.master("local")` - in this case your code will be portable, because master would be setup from the outside